# Font size decreasing according to width and height of div which size are fix

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-size

I have one div which size are fixed. div contain some dynamic text which text size increasing according to my setting. now I want to give dynamic deceasing font size because sometimes text size is big so text are go outer side of that div.

so I have lot of search and use also fitText plugin but not give result what I am want.

```css
.fix {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class=fix>

  <p>
  
  <h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  
  </h2>
  
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: if the size of the div is fixed, how can you decrease the font size based on the size of the div?

Comment: <h2> inside a <p> element is not a valid HTML.

Comment: if you want to decrease font based on character number you need to use javascript. I guess its not possible in css